# Type mismatch "bound lifetime parameter" vs "concrete lifetime" when filling a collection from a closure

Tags: closures, rust, lifetime

I am trying to find repetitions in an iterable sequence. Furthermore, I want to know the elements that occurred in that sequence up to that point.

I created a `HashMap` and am trying to call `insert` on it from within a closure used by `take_while`. However, I have so far not managed to get it to compile due to type mismatches related to concrete / bound lifetimes.

Here is a simplified version of my code which exhibits the same error:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let mut seq = HashSet::new();
    let mut insert = |k| seq.insert(k);
    (1..10).cycle().take_while(insert);
}
```

Here are the errors I get:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in closure arguments
 --> src/main.rs:6:21
  |
5 |     let mut insert = |k| seq.insert(k);
  |                      ----------------- found signature of `fn(_) -> _`
6 |     (1..10).cycle().take_while(insert);
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^ expected signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r {integer}) -> _`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'r> <[closure@src/main.rs:5:22: 5:39 seq:_] as std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r {integer},)>>::Output == bool`
 --> src/main.rs:6:21
  |
6 |     (1..10).cycle().take_while(insert);
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^ expected bound lifetime parameter, found concrete lifetime
```

How do I need to change the code for it to work?

Comment: curious, it works if the closure is moved directly into the `take_while` call: http://is.gd/OgVK2i

Comment: @ker, it works because you're doing a subtly different thing - you're using an implicit dereference in the pattern, which the original code does not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is in fact a borrowing error in disguise.

[`Iterator<Item = T>::take_while()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take_while) accepts a closure of kind `FnMut(&T) -> bool` - that is, it passes each element to the closure by reference. This is pretty much natural because `take_while()` must be able to yield the successfully tested element, so it can't pass it by value.

This means that `insert` argument type is inferred to be `&_`, and so `HashSet`'s generic parameter is also inferred as `&_`. However, this means that you're attempting to store references to temporary values yielded by the `cycle()` iterator to a structure which lives much longer. This is not allowed by borrowing rules. Unfortunately, Rust doesn't show exactly this reasoning because for some reason it can't infer that the numeric type is `i32` and it also can't infer the correct lifetime parameter for the closure. That's what your error is about.

Instead, your closure should dereference the argument before storing it to the set. [This works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=03916b4611e4f7736948&version=stable):

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let mut seq = HashSet::new();
    let mut insert = |&k: &i32| seq.insert(k);
    (1..10).cycle().take_while(insert);
}
```

I had to add the full type of the argument too; as I said above, I think that the type inference is not powerful enough to deduce it.

BTW, you can actually get the borrow checker error if you specify the type explicitly:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let mut seq = HashSet::new();
    let mut insert = |k: &i32| seq.insert(k);  // no dereference
    (1..10).cycle().take_while(insert);
}
```

The code above is equivalent to your original example except for the explicit type annotation, and it results in the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/main.rs:5:43
  |
5 |     let mut insert = |k: &i32| seq.insert(k);
  |                                           ^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 5:22...
 --> src/main.rs:5:22
  |
5 |     let mut insert = |k: &i32| seq.insert(k);
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected &i32, found &i32)
 --> src/main.rs:5:43
  |
5 |     let mut insert = |k: &i32| seq.insert(k);
  |                                           ^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the block suffix following statement 1 at 5:5...
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
5 | /     let mut insert = |k: &i32| seq.insert(k);
6 | |     (1..10).cycle().take_while(insert);
7 | | }
  | |_^
note: ...so that variable is valid at time of its declaration
 --> src/main.rs:5:9
  |
5 |     let mut insert = |k: &i32| seq.insert(k);
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: "I had to add the full type of the argument too; as I said above, I think that the type inference is not powerful enough to deduce it." I ran into such errors a few times. It is always with closures in a let binding. There seems to be a difference in how they are instantiated. Not specifying the type of the parameter to be a reference then the resulting inferred reference seems to be early bound with the lifetime of the closure's scope, while specifying the type to be a reference results in a closure with the expected higher kinded lifetime.