# Why does this simple closure fail while the other two functions succeed?

Tags: rust, closures

I've constructed a closure example that I can't get to work, nor can I find any reason why it shouldn't work.  Why does it fail to compile on the last closure?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d415fbc74c0bed445dc07a19c21aea57)

```
struct S {}

fn filter<P>(predicate: P)
where
    P: Fn(&S) -> bool,
{
    predicate(&S {});
}

fn main() {
    // this works
    filter(|_s| true);

    // this also works
    fn cb1(_s: &S) -> bool {
        true
    }
    filter(cb1);

    // but this doesn't work
    let cb2 = |_s| true;
    filter(cb2);
}
```

Output:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in closure arguments
  --> /tmp/closure.rs:19:5
   |
18 |     let cb2 = |_s| true;
   |               --------- found signature of `fn(_) -> _`
19 |     filter(cb2);
   |     ^^^^^^ expected signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r S) -> _`
   |
note: required by `filter`
  --> /tmp/closure.rs:3:1
   |
3  | fn filter<P>(predicate: P) where P: Fn(&S) -> bool,
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'r> <[closure@/tmp/closure.rs:18:15: 18:24] as std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r S,)>>::Output == bool`
  --> /tmp/closure.rs:19:5
   |
19 |     filter(cb2);
   |     ^^^^^^ expected bound lifetime parameter, found concrete lifetime
   |
note: required by `filter`
  --> /tmp/closure.rs:3:1
   |
3  | fn filter<P>(predicate: P) where P: Fn(&S) -> bool,
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Type mismatches resolving a closure that takes arguments by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36415348/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From following [Type mismatches resolving a closure that takes arguments by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36415348/155423) and [How to declare a lifetime for a closure argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403723/how-to-declare-a-lifetime-for-a-closure-argument/46198877#46198877) it appears the solution is to change:

```
fn filter<P>(predicate: P)
where
    P: Fn(&S) -> bool,
{
    predicate(&S {});
}
```

to

```
fn filter<'a, P>(predicate: P)
where
    P: Fn(&'a S) -> bool,
{
    predicate(&S {});
}
```

Though I'm not sure why.  It seems to be related to inferred lifetimes when a closure is specified inline vs when it is stored in a variable and used later.  But it's unclear why `&S` needs an `'a` lifetime, when `&S` is not a result that is returned.  If you understand this, please explain in a comment.

Though this question is "solved", the trimmed-down failure case posted originally does not actually help my true problem, because I cannot edit the source of the code I am having trouble with https://docs.rs/walkdir/2.2.9/walkdir/struct.IntoIter.html#method.filter_entry

The issue manifested when I tried to pass a stored callback into the `filter_entry` method.  The solution would be to put in explicit lifetimes in the `filter_entry` signature, as described earlier in this post, but you can only do that if you want to edit the third party code.  I think unfortunately the answer for that particular problem is "you can't use a stored closure with `filter_entry`"

Comment: I don't think you will get a better explanation than one offered in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46198877/1600898), which is that Rust compiler (currently) simply isn't smart enough to perform the appropriate inference when the closure is in a variable.

Comment: I have been able to understand more about the problem, with the help of eddyb in [this discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41078#issuecomment-552061906).  The basic gist was that I couldn't understand why the compiler would care about the lifetime of `&'a S`, when it wasn't used as an output, nor was anything captured by the closure.  The answer is basically what @user4815162342 said, which is that the compiler isn't smart enough to know that the closure isn't storing `&S` somewhere, and so it needs a guarantee that the reference will outlive the closure.

Comment: The `constrain` function from the "How to declare..." answer is actually applicable here as well! One just has to be careful to apply `constrain` to the closure _literal_, and not later at the `filter` invocation site (as was my first attempt). See my answer for a runnable example.

Answer (score 1):

> I think unfortunately the answer for that particular problem is "you can't use a stored closure with `filter_entry`"

The approach from [Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403723/how-to-declare-a-lifetime-for-a-closure-argument/46198877#46198877) can be applied to achieve this goal. Like in that answer, we can define a generic `constrain` function requiring a type with the kind of lifetime bounds that will be required to satisfy `filter`. We apply the function to the closure and *then* store it to. Note that calling `constrain(cb)` when invoking `filter` (which was my first attempt) doesn't work because the compiler cannot infer the type of the closure variable when it is passed to `constrain` any more than it could when it was being passed to `filter`.

The invocation of `constrain` has no effect at run-time, it just guides the compiler to infer the lifetime bounds for the variable that we need for `filter`. This allows storing the closure and calling `filter` without modifying its signature:

```
fn constrain<F>(fun: F) -> F
where
    F: for<'a> Fn(&'a S) -> bool,
{
    fun
}

fn main() {
    let cb = constrain(|_s| true);
    filter(cb);
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1ae057a4f4e89e46f083977dbbe92de6)