# Polymorphic closures in Rust

Tags: rust, closures, higher-rank-types

I'm starting to learn Rust (apologies in advance) and I'm trying to implement a monadic parser combinator library. Parsers implement a `Parser` trait as follows:

```
// parse success is a value + the rest of input
type ParseResult<'a, T> = Option<(T, &'a str)>;

trait Parser<A> {
    fn parse<'a>(&self, input: &'a str) -> ParseResult<'a, A>;
}
```

That is: the `parse` method is lifetime-polymorphic. This trait can be implemented for lifetime-polymorphic functions/closures using Higher-Rank Trait Bounds as follows:

```
// parser impl for functions
impl<F, A> Parser<A> for F
where
    for<'a> F: Fn(&'a str) -> ParseResult<'a, A>,
{
    fn parse<'a>(&self, input: &'a str) -> ParseResult<'a, A> {
        self(input)
    }
}
```

My problem is that closures don't automatically satisfy the `Parser` trait. Instead, it seems the type-checker needs some help from the programmer:

```
// higher-rank helper
fn cast<A, F>(func: F) -> impl Parser<A>
where
    F: for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> ParseResult<'a, A>,
{
    func
}

// applicative pure parser
fn pure<A: Copy>(a: A) -> impl Parser<A> {
    // doesn't work without explicit cast
    cast(move |input| Some((a, input)))
}
```

Without the explicit cast, the error is:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'a> <[closure@src/lib.rs:29:5: 29:34 a:_] as std::ops::FnOnce<(&'a str,)>>::Output == std::option::Option<(A, &'a str)>`
  --> src/lib.rs:27:27
   |
27 | fn pure<A: Copy>(a: A) -> impl Parser<A> {
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected bound lifetime parameter 'a, found concrete lifetime
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Parser<A>` for `[closure@src/lib.rs:29:5: 29:34 a:_]`
   = note: the return type of a function must have a statically known size
```

My questions are the following:

- Is this behavior normal? (i.e. the fact that the closure type remains lifetime-monomorphic when checking the `Parser` trait without explicit coercion)
- Is there a better/more idiomatic way of making closures satisfy the `Parser` trait?
- Or is this approach completely wrong and what would be the rusty way?

Comment: I have thought about this a bit, and it does seem a bit strange. I'm not sure if it's a bug or a limitation, but you have a workaround, so not too bad. I don't think there's any harm in reporting a bug to the Rust project - if it's not a bug, you will at least get a good explanation of what is going on!

Comment: As an aside, you don't need the `for<'a>` annotations: the `Fn*` pseudo-traits already desugar to that.

Comment: @PeterHall Thanks for your feedback. I tried removing the `for<'a>` annotations, but  I get an `undeclared lifetime` error. Actually I don't think I can skip the annotation for rank-2 types (inference is undecidable), but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @max You need to remove all mentions of the lifetime as well. It basically behaves like lifetime elision in function signatures. The constraint simply becomes `F: Fn(&str) -> ParseResult<A>`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I see, thanks!

Comment: This is a type inference problem. You can't specify the type of a closure, so it's always inferred by the compiler. The inference happens based on the context the closure appears in, but it won't take into account the trait bound on the `Parser` impl. Your cast function does not need the explicit return type – just `F` as the return type will do. The important part of that function is that it constrains the closure, so the type inference engine has enough information to infer the right type.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58773989/why-does-this-simple-closure-fail-while-the-other-two-functions-succeed

Comment: This is very similar to [this bug on the Rust repo](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41078), though there is an additional complication here due to the parametrized return type.